# Spring Data Mongodb MANIFEST.MF file suggests that Mongo 3.x is not supported?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

According to [Release Train Fowler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Fowler), there is MongoDB 3.x compatibility from version 1.7.0.RELEASE onwards. However, when I examine the MANIFEST.MF file for, say 1.9.2.RELEASE, I see the following:

```
com.mongodb;version="[2.13.0,3.0.0)"
```

which suggests that the maximum Mongo version is less than 3.0.0.

I'm misinterpreting the MANIFEST.MF file?

Thanks, Steve.

Answer (score 0):

The `MANIFEST.MF` is generated using templates. Spring Data MongoDB allows usage of both the 2.x and 3.x line of drivers. I've created [DATAMONGO-1452](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1452) to get that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I noticed that the 1.3.x bundles do not restrict the version of the mongo driver. Which versions of mongo does 1.3.x support?